# Imagemagic convert: How can we set a page "a4 Landscape"?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

Imagemagic convert:
How can we set a page "a4 Landscape"?

image Files and Folder structure:
number of jpg files: 2400.
separated into 30 folders: 80 jpgs in each folder.
Mission: create a pdf file for each folder, containing 80 images.
jpg image: 1366 x 768. (landscape)

1st trial:

> convert -page A4 *.jpg pharma_reproductive.pdf

this results in a landscape image on A4 portrait. (too much white space.)

2nd trial:

> convert -page A4 -rotate 90 *.jpg pharma_reproductive.pdf

this results in a 90 degree rotated landscape image on A4 portrait.

I can use this after 90 degree rotate on Adobe Reader everytime.
Given that there are 30 files and the number will increase,
there should be a way.

I googled with no luck, and I read the manual of imagemagic but
this geometry thing is too complicated...
(No offence, but Personally I think it should be more simplified...)

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,
Doctor

Comment: Anybody? I don't mind using other software to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I solved a similar problem (landscape US-Letter to portrait A4) by separating the size and rotation steps. For your problem, the solution could look like so:

```
convert -rotate 90 *.jpg rotate-%d.jpg
convert -page A4 rotate-%d.jpg rotate-%d.pdf  # -density 450
convert -rotate -90 rotate-%d.pdf %d.pdf
```

You may want to add parameters `-density 450`  and `-auto-orient` to get the result in a good looking way.

Comment: Does not work for me as rotating the PDF reduces the resolution of the embedded pixel images to almost nothing. any idea?

Comment: Try rotating with `-density 300x300` or whatever your target DPI is.

Comment: well. the images are of different size and stretched to fill the page. so DPI is varying...

Comment: As I understand it, `-density` controls the target DPI. So it should work independently of your source DPI.

Comment: According to "man convert", "Use any setting or operator as an output-option. Only a limited number of setting are input-option. They include: -antialias, -caption, -density, [...]"

I have had success at using -density as an input option, without the -page A4 parameter (combining them causes bad results).

Comment: Cannot test it atm. Feel free to update the answer!